# pandas dataframe holds more columns than it prints

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df which has the following:

```
df.columns
MultiIndex(levels=[[u'z1', u'z2', u'z3', u'z4', u'z5', u'z6', u'Year'], [u'Bkt2', u'Bkt5', u'Bkt7', u'Bkt8', u'']],
           labels=[[3], [2]])
```

However, when I print:

```
print(df)
                       z4
                       Bkt7
Year                              
2021                  .1
2022                  6
2023                  30201
2024                  7652
```

I have the following questions:
(1) Why do I see only 1 column when I do print as opposed to printing columns?
(2) How do I make sure that only printed column exists instead of all other columns?

Edit:
My pandas version is:

```
pd.__version__
u'0.19.2'
```

Unfortunately I can't upgrade my pandas due to dependencies on some package which fail with later version.

Answer (score 2):

From version 0.20.0 there is [`MultiIndex.remove_unused_levels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.remove_unused_levels.html#pandas-multiindex-remove-unused-levels)

```
df.columns = df.columns.remove_unused_levels()
```